# Why are parent components null when imported?

Tags: reactjs, import

https://codesandbox.io/s/2002qx2q1n

index.js:

```
import Hello from './Hello';

const App = () => (
  <div style={styles}>
    <Hello name="CodeSandbox" />
    <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen {'\u2728'}</h2>
  </div>
);

export default App
```

Hello.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './index';

console.log('App:', App)

const Hello = ({ name }) => <h1>Hello {name}!</h1>;

export default Hello
```

Logs `App: null`. How do I get `App` to be a defined component? In particular, I'm trying to access a static var on App (`App.myVar = 1`) from Hello.

Comment: ```import``` statements appear to be cyclic.. importing ```App``` in ```Home``` component and then importing ```Home``` in ```App``` component may lead to issues

Comment: They are cyclic. Is the only solution putting `myVar` in a different file, with a different namespace?

Comment: Correct, you may want to place ```myVar``` in a separate file..